# C++ cli subcommands (with tclap)

Tags: c++, command-line

I'm using tclap for my cli program. How can I add subcommands with different parameters like for example in git?
The usage should be

```
./program cmd1 <name> [email]
./program --verbose cmd2 [-p <number>]
```

Also flags for all subcommands (like the `--verbose`) should be possible.

If it's not possible with tclap, what would you suggest else?

Comment: Why don't you send an email to the author?

Comment: That's a really good idea! Could've thought about that for my own lol. Thank you

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: @FedericoCiuffardi to be honest, I don't quite remember. I'm not even sure, which project this was for. But I believe I did not solve that (with tclap) in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really part of the design of TCLAP. It's focused on providing "POSIX style" command line flags/arguments, which was the style of the day. It would probably not be too difficult to provide a git-style parser in the same spirit of TCLAP, but as of now TCLAP is probably to wrong tool for the job.